# Best way to Design Key,value pairs in relational database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has a list of all attributes that any object can have:

```
attr_id    attr_name    attr_data_type
------      -----        --------------
```

I have a table `[object_key]` in which each `object_key_id` has an unique list i.e set of attr_id,attr_value pairs.

```
object_key_id   attr_id   attr_value
---------       -------   ----------
1               1          'value1'
1               2          'value2'
2               1          'value3'
2               2          'value4'
3               1          'value1'
3               2          'value2'
3               3          'value3'
```

In this case, what is the best way to get the `object_key_id` for a given set of `attr_id,attr_value` pairs.

`Ex:  Input: [{1, 'value1'}, {2, 'value2'}]
     Output: 1`

What's the best way to build a unique index i.e to have unique `object_key_id` for a set of `attr_id,attr_value` pairs?

Comment: I don't see any row `{1, 'aba'}` and neither any row with `{123, 'bcd'}` in the data. Typos?

Comment: Updated. check now..

Comment: So, only object 1 and not 3 because object 3 has also the `{3, 'value3'}` pair, right?

Answer (score 8):

What you want is called (exact) **[Relational Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29)**.

See also this article: **[Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)**

There are several ways to have a query like that solves this problem. You can load the input data to a (temporary) table or use a CTE like this:

```
WITH input_data (attr_id, attr_value) AS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM 
      ( VALUES                              -- the input data. 
          (1, 'value1'), 
          (2, 'value2')
      ) AS i (attr_id, attr_value)
  ),
t AS                                        -- all the object_key_id values.
  ( SELECT DISTINCT object_key_id           -- if you have a separate table with those
    FROM tableX                             -- you can use it, instead. 
  )
SELECT object_key_id
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS                            -- this subquery ensures
      ( SELECT attr_id, attr_value          -- that all input attribute/value pairs
        FROM input_data                     -- appear for an object_key
      EXCEPT
        SELECT attr_id, attr_value
        FROM tableX AS tt
        WHERE tt.object_key_id = t.object_key_id 
      ) 
  AND NOT EXISTS                            -- and this subquery does the reverse
       ( SELECT attr_id, attr_value         -- i.e. the exact part of the division
        FROM tableX AS tt
        WHERE tt.object_key_id = t.object_key_id 
      EXCEPT
        SELECT attr_id, attr_value
        FROM input_data
      ) ;
```

Test at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/377f4/3)**

This question at StackOverflow: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)** has a few more ways to solve it and benchmarks for Postgres but it's not for the exact variation, only for the *"Division with Remainder"*. The queries will be similar but an extra check/condition has to be added for the exact variation.

Answer (score 0):

Relational division is the proper way to do this.

If you know what attributes your objects can have you can construct a view based on a `PIVOTED` query.  Experience shows this to be dog slow for non-trivial row counts, however.

Concatenating the attribute IDs and values, then hashing and storing an object / hash lookup has worked for me.  You have to order consistently, of course, choose delimiters carefully and deal with hash collisions.